# Openlayer: Cannot select feature from AJAX loaded values

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, openlayers

I have a problem on how to add an event from *AJAX* loaded values.

The code below works fine when the option values are pre loaded but when it is from `AJAX`, it cannot click a feature.

Here's the code:

It is placed before the closing `head` tag

```
$("#forminput").change(function() {
  var pin = $("#forminput").val();
  alert(pin);
  for (var f = 0; f < layer_agao.features.length; f++) {
      if (layer_agao.features[f].attributes.clandpin == pin) {
          $("#mybutton").click(function() {
              featsel = layer_agao.features[f];
              alert(featsel);
              selectControl.clickFeature(featsel);
          });
          break;
      }
  }
});
```

Here's my AJAX code, place before the closing `body` tag:

```
$("#formsection").change(function() {
  $('#forminput').empty();
  $.ajax({
      url: "/sectionpins",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
          'sectionid': $(this).val(),
          'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
      },
      success: function(data) {
          for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              $('#forminput').append("<option type=\"text\" value=" + data[i] + " >" + data[i] + "</option>");
          }
      },
      error: function() {
          alert('Error!!!!');
      }
  });
  return false;
});
```

This is the HTML part:

```
<select name="q" class="form-control" id="forminput" style="width: 200px">
    <option type="text">Select Section First</option>
    {% comment %} {% for pins in query_agao %}
    <option type="text" value="{{pins.clandpin}}">{{pins.clandpin}}</option>
    {% endfor %}{% endcomment %}
</select>
```

Comment: Is it a timing issue. What happens if you put the ajax call in a on body loaded event to ensure that forminput exists.

Comment: As far as I understand (can't check it right now), clickFeature is what's called on event, not an event you can run. From documentation: "Called on click in a feature Only responds if this.hover is false.". What would happen if in javascript console you'd run: selectControl.clickFeature(layer_agao.features[0]); ? And if your problem is with selection, you need to run selectControl.selectFeature(...) instead, I think.

Comment: @JohnBarça `forminput` already exist, the problem is it cannot trigger the click event when the option values are loaded from AJAX. I guess it is more on timing issue as you call it because I tried populating the option value of the `forminput` and it works fine. It can select the feature depending on its pin.